# Filtering span or mark text XPATH with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, salesforce, ui-automation

Search box is having Span autocomplete text and with mark as child attribute.
[image]

[image]

Followed the below code and manually incremented the counter to get the last item in the list.
As if the position of 'Rush Your File' in the list changes in the future, this script will fail. Please suggest a better way of handling it.

```
sendKeys(caseInput, "Rush Your File");
List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
elementList = DriverManager.driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul/li//span[text()='']//mark")).ToList();
int cntt = 0;
foreach (IWebElement element in elementList)
{
    if (element.Text == componentName)
    {
        cntt = cntt + 1;
        if (cntt == elementList.Count - 1)
        {
            JavaScriptEleClick(element);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, there are several suggested results in the autocomplete list while you want to use the one that exactly matches the inserted input text. Right?
If so you simply should take the element with text equals to the inserted string, not just containing it.
As following:

```
string inputText = "Rush Your File";
string elementXpath = String.Format("//ul/li//span[text()='{0}']//mark", inputText); 
sendKeys(caseInput, inputText);
element = DriverManager.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementXpath));
JavaScriptEleClick(element);
```

Comment: Not exactly.. I have Span and its child mark tags. mark tag contains entered search string 'Rush Your File' and span tag holds the remaining text of the list items. If you see the above images, mark holds' 'Rush Your File' and span holds '8 AE LO'. and with this i'm still  getting three results //ul/li//span[text()='']//mark as span text of null is not filtering..what is this mean > span[text()='{0}']

Comment: with span[text()='{0}']  it retrives zero results.